# Nginx display image as gibberish text

Tags: nginx

I have setup to reverse proxy port 8086. Port 8086 is running a javascript that display random a image in webp format. If I try to visit the domain it displays the image as gibberish text. It works fine if I visit the ip address but not the domain.

An example of what the gibberish text looks like:

```
RIFFZž�WEBPVP8 Nž�ð”*€°>‘B›J%£µ0&Lr    HZÚ¯>y¦I^hwå´Ö]æåÿIßë¸WôßôœÌùo÷OØ¨ñkóßòÿ³�?Ëÿ´qŸî°˜ßõ<ÑçµÿGÑôøB¿ãïÑÀSØþÿV\[ñïöÿ±ôÖãß
þëø¿ô¿ý=³ø›Ý>€ýæÃÿW¯ÚßÿÿþÉk=fìýÝøiûÛë7÷÷+Ý“ÕOõßRë¿õ?ÿöbz&y·÷ýëøœýâýÜÿÿïuÿÿUûáÿ÷?ðz‚øÿöÿø<ƒüŸÝãgãuÜ¶q¿]ú÷ûâWr<}ß÷ÿòG#Ÿ<ÐwugçùõüûÏ`NþÏ¯ÐÞýÑøþ§þ¯ÖCþ1¿µÐöò÷ÿÿï÷¯ÿÿþ_ˆ?Ü£º³Y¤þ$+¤³ÿâ…€æQvË¿½ì‰Ï{’Ô˜MÛÌŽD)ñHìäÚÊgððÇÜº5²¿tlÐ;±…Ú•‰ß\vkòž‡›ú§C‘£¤_É{ÿtï¯Sßû‰38ã Å]¾á•Ö‰ä91{®9×pkáTv]NÇþ}vGŠÄƒçæG¬¯¿oZkûqœZ£>uír%‘YEbp<sUöy€våºqÀm€°]«:Ÿ„à5Èºµ3Axqzí$¦‘½ÀQq²Ý_•XñÆk9N~ò´>*‘`{ƒßú/BºK>P®Âœ¢Õ¤"Ò÷–«JbZ�$_×u¹öÙÍp½A¦åþiËÔg'ÊÔÝ9qàÅH¦.wØ\>¨[Ä#>½+AW‰héi_åÀ‰¥9Šzu¤«(§bc§F«à'•¡›¼W‚Nõí4íâô RšÁ‚Ÿ5qö5
```

Here's my nginx conf

```
server {


    server_name wall.example.moe www.wall.example.moe;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/wall.example.moe.access.log ;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/wall.example.moe.error.log;

    add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.172.241:8086/img;
        proxy_redirect      off;
        include proxy_params;
    }

    # Security settings for better privacy
    # Deny hidden files
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known\/) {
        deny all;
    }
    # letsencrypt validation
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        alias /var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
        allow all;
        auth_basic off;
    }

}
```

Anyone know how to fix this? I just want it to display image and not gibberish text

Comment: What are you actually trying to display? Please add URL (even anonymized) and file type/format. This looks like an Unicode mishap.

Comment: @Massimo trying to display an image in webp format

Comment: this looks like the web server and/or web browser is trying to interpreting the content as text when it's not. Have a look at mime types settings.

Comment: "It works fine if I visit the ip address but not the domain." What IP address are you referring here to? Please provide complete URL of a working and a failing request. Please also add output of `nginx -T` so we can see the full nginx configuration.